# change du behaviour not abort but skip

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, disk

I am running this `puppy`

````
root# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.6 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/" ```
````

An unnecessary effort to access an antivirus program gives me this:

```
$ du -hs   /mnt/sda2
du: cannot access ‘/mnt/sda2/ProgramData/Comodo/CCAV/Flsdata.db-journal’: Input/output error
Aborted
```

I want that to be ignored, i.e. `du` should skip this error and continue.  Is there any option that can do this or a workaround using an alternative utility?

Comment: Is it only this specific file? Is it enough to tell `du` to skip this file or can there be more such errors?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't abort of filesystem access errors but it seemingly aborts on IO errors which simply should not occur on a normally functioning system.

Your error could indicate that your disk is dying which should warrant a replacement or some action.

You can always exclude anything by using:

```
       --exclude=PATTERN
              exclude files that match PATTERN
```

In you case that would be `--exclude="/mnt/sda2/ProgramData/Comodo/CCAV/Flsdata.db-journal"`.